# python tkinter inside class - getting state of widgets

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I've written a program and I'm learning about classes and thus, rewriting the code to take advantage of classes and objects.

My problem is if I create a tkinter widget "dropdown menu" from a class, I can not retrieve the get.state variable.

```
class ...:
    def make_drop_menu(self,parent,drop_opts,drop='empty',state=''):
        self.parent = parent
        self.drop = drop
        self.drop_opts = drop_opts

        self.state = tk.StringVar()
        self.state.set(self.drop_opts[0])  # sets default value on drop (drop down menu)
        self.drop = OptionMenu(self.parent, self.state, *self.drop_opts)  # completed drop
        return self.drop
----------------
class main:

self.widget = self.var.make_drop_menu(self.obj_mainwindow.btm_frame, self.col_opts)


Added for clearity:
window = windowclass() #windowclass is the style for tkinter. Makes a tkwindow.
self.widget = self.windowclass.var.make_drop_Menu() #
```

I've left out some code to simplify. But my main problem is that I create a widget called self.widget which builds my drop down menu. However, I have NO idea how to get the state of the drop down.

Hopefully the code makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your class is named `MyClass`, then to access the `state` variable you would use the instance of the class. In your case it appears that `self.var` is the instance of your class, so it would look something like this:

```
self.var = MyClass()
self.var.make_drop_menu(...)
...
print(self.var.state.get())
```

Comment: The obj is the TK window that is opened. Inside that object, there are methods to create widgets. 
```
So self.var = class_window 
dropmenu = self.var.make_drop_menu() # creates the drop menu
but I cant access the state of the drop menu at this point
```

Comment: @EricConnaisseur: I'm not sure I understand you. The bottom line is that your `state` variable is an instance variable of the class. So, like any instance variable of any class, you reference it through the instance.

Comment: I believe my issue is that I have a class inside a class.
I moved the make_drop_menu class so that it not dependent on anything else.
This method doubles the lines it takes to make a drop down menu, but enables me to access the variables as needed.

So I guess its solved.

Comment: @EricConnaisseur: your use of terminology is very confusing. `make_drop_menu` isn't a class, it's a method. If you do indeed have a literal class definition inside another class definition, you should probably stop doing that. It makes the code hard to understand, and doesn't usually provide any extra value over defining the inner class at the global level.

Answer (score 0):

Made the make_drop_menu class independent of any other class object. That way I could make a drop menu, assign the parent tk window, and create a method for getting the state variable when called.
Thanks to Bryan Oakley for the help!